# Odoo v16 enterprise email template modification

Tags: email, odoo, qweb

Good morning, I want a list of followers (email address) to be added at the beginning of every email coming from odoo, regardless of whether it is an internal user or not.
Can anyone suggest how to get it?
I cannot modify files (enterprise version), only settings possible from the backend.

Tried this code

```
% for follower in object.message_follower_ids:

${follower.name} ${follower.email}

% endfor
```

but it is not working in qweb